# To get a new array with some fields of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I am working some arrays in Ionic Angular and i have this code:

```
this.items = [];
this.places = [{"first_name":"joe","last_name":"Jobs","description":"engineer"},
          {"first_name":"mary","last_name":"trump","description":"doctor"}];
```

I need to get this:

```
this.items =[{"first_name":"joe","description":"engineer"},{"first_name":"mary","description":"doctor"}];
```

I have this

```
        this.places.forEach((item) => {
        this.items.push('{"name:"'+ 
        item.first_name+',"description":'+item.description+'}');
    }
```

I got this eror message:

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Can somebody guide me in the right way?

Answer (score 2):

You can just push the object directly to items[]

```js
items=[]
places = [{"first_name":"joe","last_name":"Jobs","description":"engineer"},
          {"first_name":"mary","last_name":"trump","description":"doctor"}];

places.forEach((item) => {
      items.push({
        name:item.first_name,
        description:item.description
      })
});

console.log(items)
```

Comment: It seems to be right! Because `this.items` inside the body of the forEach callback function is undefined, so there is no `push` method to call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, like this:

```js
this.places = [{"first_name":"joe","last_name":"Jobs","description":"engineer"},
          {"first_name":"mary","last_name":"trump","description":"doctor"}];

// Using map function
this.items = this.places.map(x => ({first_name: x.first_name, description: x.description}));

console.log(this.items);
console.log('========');

this.items = [];

// Using forEach loop
this.places.forEach(item => {
    this.items.push({name: item.first_name, description: item.description});
})

console.log(this.items);
console.log('========');

this.items = [];

// Using for loop
for (var item of this.places) {
    this.items.push({name: item.first_name, description: item.description});
}

console.log(this.items);
```